# C++ template instantiation with identity argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have ran into yet another problem I do not understand.

The following does not instantiate (argument instantiation fails), why?

```
template<class E>
void operator[](typename boost::mpl::identity<E>::type e) const;
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`identity` can be used to force you to specify the template argument explicitly.  It effectively prevents that function parameter from partaking in template argument deduction.

A qualified type name is one of the non deduced contexts; that is, `identity<E>::type` will not be used to deduce the template parameter for `E`.

For example, if you have:

```
template<class E>
void f(typename boost::mpl::identity<E>::type e) { }

f(42);      // won't work
f<int>(42); // works
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems awfully redundant. `identity<E>::type` is guaranteed to be equivalent to `E`, so why not just declare your template as:

```
template<class E>
void operator[](E e) const;
```

Comment: curiosity, also potential to replace identity with "filter" sfinae

Comment: Can you post the exact compiler errors that you're receiving?